# В Cordova не работает AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, mobile-development

Делаю приложение на Cordova и мне нужно работать с БД.
В браузере всё работает хорошо, но в эмуляторе отказывается.

Нашёл, что проблема может быть в политиках безопасности, я их закомментировал.

```
<!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src &apos;self&apos; data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com &apos;unsafe-eval&apos;; style-src &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos;; media-src *; img-src &apos;self&apos; data: content:;"> -->
```

Не помогло.

В config.xml:

```
    <access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

Плагин `cordova-plugin-whitelist` установлен.

Пробовал alert. В эмуляторе он работает. Не срабатывает именно $.get();

```
$(document).ready (function() {
  $.get(          
   pathPhotoPhp, 
   {id: "1"},
   function (data) {         
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      $("#photosMain").append($("<img class='gallery_photo' src='img/"+data[i]+"'/>"));
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что надо обращаться не к localhost, а к 10.0.2.2 для эмулятора android.
И надо в php файле прописать:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Comment: Почему-то не помогает в Android SDK 28 :( Хотя с 27 работало. Вы не сталкивались с такой проблемой и её решением ?